# How can I mathematically express the difference between two vectors?

Tags: vectors

I need help regarding this as I'm not a mathematician.

Given two vectors $A$ and $B$ I need to calculate the vector $C$ containing the difference between every two corresponding components. For example, let $A = [4,5,6]$ and $B = [1,2,3]$. Then $C = [3,3,3]$.

Can I mathematically express this as follows? $C = A - B$?

Comment: Yes, you can. That is actually very much standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help.